# Creating C# dll that will be accessed via VBScript

Tags: c#, dll, vbscript

I created a C# dll using Visual Studio 2010.
I'm able to register it using regasm. I also used [ComVisible(true)] for my class.
The issue is, I'm not able to access this dll from VBScript.
I remeber there was a setting in the Project | Properties screen.
What is that setting? Or is there another way?

Comment: The option you are thinking of is making is ComVisible.  If you registered the dll then you should be able to communicate with it.

Comment: Applying the [ProgId("foo.bar")] attribute on your class helps you avoid guessing at the name to use in vbscript.  And don't forget to use the /codebase option in Regasm.exe

Comment: I had to go to the Project Properties, then assign it a signature.

Answer (score 0):

see this excellent post on creating COM components using Visual C#.NET
http://blog.stevedoria.net/20051008/creating-com-components-using-visual-csharp-dot-net